# cocoa pods, header files not visible

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm using DZNPhotoPickerController pod, I've successfully installed cocoa pods and installed the pod I needed.

trying to import a header file from the pod in a class inside my product, it doesn't help with autocomplete, yet on giving it full path

```
#import <DZNPhotoPickerController/Classes/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController+Edit.h>
```

it works, this not my first time with pods, I know this wrong but I don't know why it works like this.

Comment: any solution ? Getting the same problem.

Comment: it was the version of cocoa pods, try uninstall and installing version 0.38.2 , worked after then.